# How to record a two minut video using pc camera and store it pc locally in vb.net using iis server and notepad

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7

I have a one table in which 3 column , one in question column other is record video and last is upload.
My problem is that when user click on record Button we record two minut video
and Save it PC Locally and so on .
i am using notepad , internet information Service and front end in  aspx and back end in vb .net
i have this code check it  this is aspx file extension that i store on IIS server and use it[see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVhH9.png)

```
     <%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Security" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="AForge.Video" %>
     <%@ Import Namespace="AForge.Video.DirectShow" %>


     <script runat="server">

     Protected  Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' here to write a code for record a video   


     End Sub












     </script>

     <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html>

     <head>

     <Style>
     #center_div
     {
        position: absolute;
        height: 200px;
        width: 850px;
        margin: -100px 0 0 -200px;
        top:20%;
        left: 30%;

     }
      table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
      }
      th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

    th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    }
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
     th {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </Style>



    <title> Sign Up </title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="center_div">

    <form  runat="server" id="myform">

    <fieldset>

    <legend>Answers the Question:</legend> 
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Question</th><th>Record Videos</th><th>Upload</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label" Style="width:500px">What is Your Name and Why we Take           Admission  in our university </td><td Style="width:200px"> <asp:Button  ID="Button9" runat="server" Text="Record" onClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
    <td Style="width:200px"> <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Upload" onClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label" Style="width:500px">Why you Select this univeristy for  Study </td><td Style="width:200px"> <asp:Button ID="Button10" runat="server" Text="Record" onClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
    <td Style="width:200px"> <asp:Button ID="Button30" runat="server" Text="Upload" onClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="label" Style="width:500px">Why you Select this univeristy for   Study </td><td Style="width:200px"> <asp:Button ID="Button101" runat="server" Text="Record" onClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
    <td Style="width:200px"> <asp:Button ID="Button301" runat="server"   Text="Upload" onClick="Button1_Click" /></td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" onClick="Button1_Click" />


   <asp:Label ID = "Label2" runat = "server" text="" Style="color:red">    </asp:Label>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Hello.  I guess we cannot help you in your work if you didn't really start.  You should detail what you have already try and where you are stuck.

Comment: i do not know which tag is used in HTML to display a video and which classes is used in back end to store video

Answer (score 1):

For recording a video Directx Library is used in c#
But in Asp .net Application can not used Directx on the client machine.So alternative used to flash , sliver light or Html 5.
So I solve My Problem By using Jquery Plugin for recording a video .

### Video.js Record ##

[Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record)

This Plugin is record my  video and store on my pc.For recording a video it is very good plugin for record a  video on server side in asp .net .